# OnBindViewHolder on a different recyclerview gets called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have something very strange happening in my code recently. My android application has a tablayout setup with viewpager. each tab contains a recyclerview. The first tab has the fragment "FeedFragment" that has the recyclerview setup with the Adapter "FeedAdapter" and the 3rd tab has the fragment "NotificationFragment" that has the recyclerview setup with "NotificationAdapter" that sets the recyclerview.
The issue is, when I go to the notifications tab, "OnBindViewHolder" method of the FeedAdapter is called each time. I have no idea why this is happening cuz there's nothing in my code that should make it happen. Here's my code for the NotificationFragment class:

```
         ISharedPreferences pref = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("UserInfo", FileCreationMode.Private);
        string userName = pref.GetString("Username", String.Empty);
        // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
        // return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.YourFragment, container, false);

        DBRepository dbr = new DBRepository();

        notifications = dbr.GetNotificationMember(userName);

        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.notificationsView, container, false);

        empty = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.empty);
        //pb.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        notifitem = view.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.rv);
        notifitem.HasFixedSize = true;

        if (notifications.Count == 0)
        {
            empty.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            empty.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        }

        layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(Activity);
        adapter = new NotificationAdapter(notifications, Activity);

        notifitem.SetLayoutManager(layoutmanager);
        notifitem.SetAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
```

The OnBindViewHolder method is called right after the view is returned from the NotificationFragment. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Have you printed log messages in both the adapters' `OnBindViewHolder`s to make sure that indeed FeedAdapter's method is being called?

Comment: I have put a break point inside the FeedAdapter's OnBindViewHolder method that get's hit every time the NotificationsFragment is active.

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba : Did you find a solution to your problem? I am also facing the same issue.
Thank You!